# Navigation graph with viewpager2 android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-viewpager2, android-navigation-graph

My viewpager consists of 2 fragments which are displayed correctly and working fine.

From viewpager's fragment I want to move to another fragment via navigation graph

This is my graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/offer_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/offersFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/offersFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.offers.OffersFragment"
    android:label="offers_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/offers_fragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/availableOfferDetailFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.offers.available.AvailableOfferDetailFragment"
    android:label="fragment_available_offer_detail"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_available_offer_detail" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/availableOffersFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.offers.available.AvailableOffersFragment"
    android:label="fragment_available_offers"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_available_offers" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_availableOffersFragment_to_availableOfferDetailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/availableOfferDetailFragment" >
        <argument
            android:name="offerId"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="-1" />
    </action>
</fragment>
</navigation>
```

Offers fragment - has view pager
Available offer fragment - one of the fragment on view pager
Available offer detail fragment - i want to navigate

On button click I am calling this

```
AvailableOffersFragmentDirections.actionAvailableOffersFragmentToAvailableOfferDetailFragment(offerId)
```

The exception

```
Navigation action/destination com.octave.staging:id/action_availableOffersFragment_to_availableOfferDetailFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.octave.staging:id/homeFragment) label=HomeFragment class=com.octave.home.HomeFragment
```

What is wrong over here?

Comment: Do you want to navigate from `availableOffersFragment` to `availableOfferDetailFragment` or from `offersFragment` .. i.e. which fragment the button exist?

Comment: @Zain button exists on availableOffersFragment. I want to navigate from availableOffersFragment to availableOfferDetailFragment. offersFragment has the viewpager with 2 tabs having their own fragment - availableOffersFragment and secondFragemnt

Answer (score 2):

> button exists on availableOffersFragment. I want to navigate from
> availableOffersFragment to availableOfferDetailFragment.
> offersFragment has the viewpager with 2 tabs having their own fragment
> availableOffersFragment and secondFragemnt

So, now you need to navigate from `availableOffersFragment` which is a tab (page fragment) in the ViewPager; but this is not possible because those tabs don't affect the back stack. You can check out the questions discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630267/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-bottomnavigationview-using-new-navigation-arch) and also [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298137/viewpager-with-navigation-architecture-components)

But what you can do instead is to add an action from offersFragment (which holds the ViewPager) to availableOfferDetailFragment as following:

- Remove the tab fragments from the navGraph (`availableOffersFragment` and `secondFragemnt`).
- Create an action in the navGraph from offersFragment to  availableOfferDetailFragment

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/offersFragment"
        android:name="com.octave.offers.OffersFragment"
        android:label="offers_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/offers_fragment">
        
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_offersFragment_to_availableOfferDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/availableOfferDetailFragment" >
            <argument
                android:name="offerId"
                app:argType="integer"
                android:defaultValue="-1" />
        </action>
    </fragment>
```

- When the button is clicked use `parentFragment` to access the `offersFragment` from the `availableOffersFragment` tab when the button is clicked. For instance:

Create a method in `offersFragment`:

```
goToDetailsFragment(offerId: Int) {
    // perfrom the navaigation
    OffersFragmentDirections.actionOffersFragmentToAvailableOfferDetailFragment(offerId)
}
```

And in `availableOffersFragment`

```
btn.setOnClickListener {
       (parentFragment as offersFragment).goToDetailsFragment(offerId)
}
```

Comment: can you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810)

Comment: did you check issue?

Comment: Yes let me know if can answer it, give me some time pls

Comment: @vivekmodi Excuses as I didn't work much with paging3 library

Comment: @Zain Sorry to call you here (I wasn't sure where else to call you), but could you help me know how to become a Mobile Development Recognized  Member on the Android Collectives? I've been trying to be more active on Stack Overflow and found that there would be a good place to start.

Comment: @LeonardoSibela Np, I am not totally aware of the requirements of being recognized member to the Android collective community; It's not something that I opt in directly, but I believe it's all about the qualities of a one's answers and question and over all participation in StackOverflow; and they will put you in automatically after asking you. Hopefully you'd get the best :)

Comment: @Zain thanks so much and I'm sorry I called you here. Have a great week :)

Answer (score 0):

Check using:

```
btn.setOnClickListener {
       Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.availableOfferDetailFragment)
}
```