# ViewPager with Navigation architecture components

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-architecture-components

Are there any uses for navigation with the viewpager? I can not find information about this and I do not understand how this can be done.

I have an simple two fragments which is need to put inside viewpager and if its possible via navigation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a ViewPager using new Navigation Architecture Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630267/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-using-new-navigation-architecture-component)

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon It looks like a workaround, not a good approach. Navigation interferes and does not help. In my opinion quick answer on my question is NO.

Comment: This is not the duplicate of that question, that question is about ViewPager2 with BottomNavigationView.

Comment: If you are looking for Navigation Component implementation only with ViewPager or ViewPager + TabLayout and back navigation with `OnBackPressedCallback` you can check out the answer i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62530288/5457853)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122087752):

> Navigation focuses on elements that affect the back stack and tabs do not affect the back stack - you should continue to manage tabs with a [ViewPager and TabLayout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ)

Comment: What do you think about this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/54355659/6272369 ?

Comment: You should never use `BottomNavigationView` with a `ViewPager`, as per the [transitions sections of the material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior), but having a separate navigation graph for each screen in the ViewPager is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I have implemented BottomNavigationView and ViewPager with having a separate navigation graph for each screen in the ViewPager.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569473/4723178

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsood - as per the [Transitions section of the Material Design guidelines for bottom nav](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior), you should never be using a ViewPager and BottomNavigationView together.

Comment: There is a pretty confusing disconnect here between BottomNavigationView vs TabLayout back stacks: bottom bars work with the nav component using some custom nav controller behavior. However if you want a TabLayout instead, FragmentPagerAdapters use programmatic Fragments so while a similar behavior to bottom-nav views is required, I can't quite see a way to do it.

Comment: I have my viewpager inside fragment, I want to start a new navigation graph for each fragment of viewpager. Can you give me a piece of code for, how to set NavHostFragment from the viewpager's fragment.

Comment: @Swapnika - as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#create_a_navhostfragment), you'd probably want to use `NavHostFragment.create()`.

Comment: @Swapnika you can take a look to my experiment here: https://github.com/muhrahmatullah/televisi

Comment: "You should never use BottomNavigationView with a ViewPager" that's a strong statement. ViewPager2 has the option to disable the swiping gesture, multi-pane fragments inside one of the bottom nav pages is not uncommon. I found it's very convenient to use ViewPager(2) to implement my designers' flow.