# Android Jetpack navigationUI , how to pass data to view pager fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-viewpager, android-jetpack

I am first time working with `Navigation UI Architecture Component`

I am trying to use ViewPager with it. I wanted to pass argument to Fragments that's is added to `viewpager`

I didn't found any solution related to `viewpager`

**My code**

```
class StoriesPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager?)
    :FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager){

    private val sections= arrayListOf("science","technology","business","world","movies","travel")

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        val bundle=Bundle()
        bundle.putString("section",sections[position])
        Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_masterFragment_to_timesListFragment,bundle)
        return TimesListFragment()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return sections.size

    }


    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return sections[position]
    }
}
```

**My navigation graph**

- MasterFragment -> contains TabLayout , ViewPager
- passes `section` key to ListFragment via `FragmentPagerAdapter`
- ListFragment -> shows api response based on `section` key
- DetailsFragmenst

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in fragment instance:

```
class StoriesPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager?)
:FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager){

private val sections= arrayListOf("science","technology","business","world","movies","travel")

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return TimesListFragment().newInstance(sections)
}

override fun getCount(): Int {

    return sections.size

}


override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return sections[position]
 }
}
```

You have to manage viewPager like old method with navigation architecture according to this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298808/10511266)

Comment: When I made navigation graph "return TimesListFragment().newInstance(sections)" doesn't makes any difference . It expects the data to be passed via Navigation UI way.