# Handling backstack in jetpack navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using `BottomNavigationView` with Jetpack Navigation. I have also set all Fragments as top level destination.

```
val host : NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return
        val navController = host.navController
        val appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(topLevelDestinationIds = setOf(R.id.library_fragment,R.id.account_fragment,R.id.calender_fragment,R.id.home_fragment,R.id.notice_fragment))
        val bottomNavView = binding.bottomNavView

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfig)
        bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

On second bottom navigation menu item there is  `LibraryFragment` in which I am using `TabLayout`. There is `LibraryFoldersFragment` corresponding to a Tab inside of `LibraryFragment`. `LibraryFoldersFragment` contains a `RecyclerView`. On clicking `RecyclerView` item, `LibraryFilesFragment` will replace `LibraryFoldersFragment`.

```
val fragment = LibraryFilesFragment.newInstance(item)
                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
                    .commit()
```

[image: Here is the Screenshot of my app]

The problem is that on pressing back button in `LibraryFilesFragment` app is navigated directly to first bottom navigation menu item. But I want it to navigate to `LibraryFoldersFragment`.

Comment: Are you using `ViewPager2` (which fully replaces `ViewPager`)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using `ViewPager2`. I have also uploaded screenshot of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Navigation component from Jetpack, instead of committing a fragment transaction by yourself. Create a navigation xml for declaring your `LibraryFoldersFragment` to `LibraryFilesFragment` navigation. Use `findNavController().navigate()` on recyclerView Item click to navigate.
Setup bottomNavView with NavController with GraphIds of different desired nav xml created.

[Sample reference](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)

Comment: But I am using `TabLayout`. According to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540303/android-jetpack-navigation-with-viewpager-and-tablayout) One should not use `TabLayout` with Jetpack Navigation. I have also uploaded screenshot of my app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake  Are there any changes w.r.t. this in ViewPager2 against [this old issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122087752)?